# Profiling a Chrome application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, profiling

We are creating a [Chrome application](http://msgboy.com/) that we hope to release in the coming weeks. We have already distributed to a bunch of alpha testers, and, even though feedback is generally good, we have had complains by a bunch of users that our extensions is **expensive in terms of RAM**.
We also had reports of a **too high CPU consumption**.

Now, we have improved what seemed obvious, but *we are almost 'blind' in terms of execution*.

What would be the good strategy to profile both memory and JS calls for our Chrome application?

Please note that this application is a full native application, so maybe we can apply some generic javascript profiling tips?

Comment: All I have used are Chrome Dev panels: Timeline and Profiles - I assume that you have checked them thoroughly.

Comment: I did check them, but couldn't find the way to use them efficiently. Any resource that you think I could look at to get started?

Comment: Did you look through the profile docs? They cover everything pretty well and there are a number of videos with good intros. http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/profiles.html

Comment: Abraham's link is dead on. I'd point specifically to the [heap profiling documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/heap-profiling.html) as a good place for you to start determining exactly how your application is using memory.

Answer (score 0):

As people have mentioned, you can use the Chrome Developer Tools to profile memory usage.

For CPU and RAM, it's not particularily scientific, but you could get a broad gauge by having no applications open other than Chrome which has about:blank open and your OS' Activity Monitor or Task Manager.

Look at the CPU and RAM readings for Chrome on about:blank, which is about as idle as it will get - then compare that to the readings when your Application is running.

Disable all extensions too, to take them out of the equation.

Hope this helps.